# YII: Updating my Values not working

Tags: php, yii

I am kinda new to Yii and i am finding some things not funny. I have a form that i want to update and it keeps throwing errors each time, when i'm trying to update it.

View: **_form.php**

```
<?php
/* @var $this BaseStationController */
/* @var $model BaseStation */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'base-station-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

         <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'c_id'); ?>
            <select name="BaseStation[c_id]">
                <?php foreach($models as $m):?> //Here coded the loop below to display customer's id from the database
                    <option value='<?php echo $m->id;?>'><?php echo $m->firstname.' '.$m->lastname;?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'base_station_num'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'base_station_num',array('size'=>15,'maxlength'=>15)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'base_station_num'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
        </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['BaseStation']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['BaseStation'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,

        ));
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Error: Undefined variable: data.. Sorry i forgot to post my actionCreate method: public function actionCreate()
public function actionCreate(){

  $this->render('create',array(
   'model'=>$model,
            'data'=>$data
  ));
 }

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty straightforward: the data variable is undefined. You are passing the $data to the view file in the create action, but not in the update action. Also you do no use the data variable in the _form view. Is it used in the create/update view? If not, why do you pass the $data variable? Where does it come from? You do not initialize it or the model variables in the create action either.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['BaseStation']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['BaseStation'];
            $model->c_id = $model->c_id;
            $model->base_station_num = $model->base_station_num;
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,

        ));
    }
```

try this

Comment: Yes, you need to load the model first before any new values can be saved.